# Фильтр данных с pydantic по значениям

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

Имеется результат от запроса к API, например, такого вида:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "info": "foo",
      "service_type": "type1"
    },
    {
      "info": "bar",
      "service_type": "type2"
    },
    {
      "info": "baz",
      "service_type": "typy3"
    },
    {
      "info": "zzz",
      "service_type": "type4"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Есть классы:

```
class Server(BaseModel):

    info: str 
    service_type: str 

    class Config:
        extra = 'ignore'


class Servers(BaseModel):

    result: list[Server]

    class Config:
        extra = 'ignore'
```

Возможно ли используя **pydantic** отфильровать данные по значениям определенного поля?
С помощью extra = 'ignore' я убрал все ненужные мне данные в результате запроса.
А вот дальше нужно исключить по определенным значениям для поля **service_type**.
Например, не нужно сохранять в модель, если значение **service_type** равно type4 или type5.
Т.е. не нужно кидать исключение, а просто не сохранять их и получить результат только с **service_type** содержащим type1, type2 или type3.

Comment: Получите все, а потом отфильтруйте по значению service_type.

Comment: Да я так в итоге так сделал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю идеологию pydantic, то он не создан для фильтрации входных значений, его основная задача валидация данных грубо говоря чуть более расширенный функционал 'строгой' типизации для питона.
Из документации pydantic

> Data validation and settings management using python type annotations.
>
> pydantic enforces type hints at runtime, and provides user friendly
> errors when data is invalid.
>
> Define how data should be in pure, canonical python; validate it with
> pydantic.

В вашей текущей задачи лучше не пытаться использовать инструмент, который для этой задачи не подходит, а взять инструмент, который уже подойдёт для задачи выборки.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: @Тор если я ответил на ваш вопрос, пометьте его пожалуйста как выполненный.

Comment: Отметил, спасибо.